# Keywords in python that evaluate to themselves

Tags: python, clojure, keyword, abstract-data-type

There's a notion of keywords in Clojure where you define them by adding a colon in front of your word you are trying to address as a keyword. Also, it evaluates to itself. For example:

```
:my-keyword 
;=> :my-keyword
```

Is there any way to implement this in python by defining some custom class or any workarounds?

The reason for having this is to have more self-desctriptive parameters (strings are there, but one cannot keep track of having consistent strings while passing around).

A practical use case for this goes something like this:

```
def area(polygon_type):
  return \
  {
    "square": lambda side: (side * side),
    "triangle": lambda base, height: (0.5 * base * height)
  }[polygon_type]

area("square")(2) # ==> 4
```

But, having strings in such manner leads to error at runtime, if mishandled. But having something like keywords even an auto-complete feature in any IDE suggests the mistake that has been made while passing in the *polygon_type*.

```
area("Sqaure")(2) # would lead to a KeyError
```

Is there some feature in python that solves this type of problem, that I am unaware of?
If not, how'd someone go about tackling this?

Edit:
I am not trying to solve the problem of having such a function in particular; but instead looking for a way of implementing *keyword* concept in python. As, with enums I have to bundle up and explicitly define them under some category (In this case *polygon_type*)

Comment: use clojure and use a subprocess to run your python. That's not too wise to do.

Comment: Are you asking if there is way python can find & work around typos in your code?

Comment: You could use an enum. You could use type hints. IDEs probably check that kind of thing.

Comment: @khelwood Not exactly. Because with enums I'll have to bundle the terms like in the above example into a single enum class called PolygonType. And then use them as PolygonType.square and PolygonType.triangle. Also will have to import the PolygonType into every module I use them; which is undesirable.

Comment: If you want have a function `area(polygon_type)` for which only a finite number of exact values are valid, and you want a tool to be able to inspect your code to see if you're trying to pass it an invalid value, enums and/or type hints seems to match that requirement. On the other hand, if what you actually want is to write Python the exact same way you would write another language, then your approach is misguided.

Comment: Nope @rdas I am asking if I can define some custom class to facilitate a custom defined syntax like in the first snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Keywords in Clojure are [interned strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) and Clojure provides special syntactic support for them. I suggest you take a look at [how they are implemented](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java). It seems like [Python does some interning of its strings](https://medium.com/@bdov_/https-medium-com-bdov-python-objects-part-iii-string-interning-625d3c7319de) but I don't know much of its details.

The point of using keyword is fast comparisons and map lookup. Although I am not sure how you would benefit from it, you could try to implement your own keyword-like objects in Python using string interning, something like this:

```
str2kwd = {}

class Keyword:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return ":" + self.s

def kwd(s):
    """Construct a keyword"""
    k = str2kwd.get(s)
    if k is None:
        k = Keyword(s)
        str2kwd[s] = k
    return k
```

Whenever you want to construct a keyword, you call the `kwd` function. For the Keyword class, we rely on the default equality and hash methods. Then you could use it like this:

```
>>> kwd("a")
:a
>>> kwd("a") == kwd("a")
True
>>> kwd("b") == kwd("a")
False
>>> kwd_a = kwd("a")
>>> kwd_b = kwd("b")
>>> {kwd_a: 3, kwd_b: 4}
{:a: 3, :b: 4}
>>> {kwd_a: 3, kwd_b: 4}[kwd_a]
3
```

However, I have not measured if this results in faster comparisons and map-lookups than just using regular Python strings, which is probably the most idiomatic choice for Python anyway. I doubt you would see a significant improvement in performance from using this home-made keyword class. Also note that it is best to call the `kwd` function at the top-level of the module and assign it to a variable that you use, instead of calling `kwd` everytime you need a keyword. Obviously, you will not have the special keyword syntax as in Clojure.

**UPDATE: How to avoid misspelling bugs**

If you are worried about misspelling keys in your map, you can assign the keys to local variables and use those local variables instead of the key values directly. This way, if you misspell a local variable name you will likely get an error much sooner because you are referring to a local variable that does not exist.

```
>>> kwd_square = "square"
>>> kwd_triangle = "triangle"
>>> m = {kwd_square: 3, kwd_triangle: 4}
>>> m[kwd_square]
3
>>> m[Square]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Square' is not defined
```

Comment: But when using these keywords across the modules, one will have to either import the "keywords" explicitly or define all the keywords beforehand in a separate module and import them as required; which doesn't comply with the idea of "keywords" of Clojure. But this clears my doubt anyways :)

Comment: As I see it, there are really two things you are asking for: (i) how to implement something like keywords in Python and (ii) how to avoid bugs related to misspelling keys. Regarding (ii), it is as possible to misspell keys in Clojure as it is in Python: If your map is `{:square 3, :triangle 4}` it is just as possible for you to incorrectly use the key `:Square` instead of the key `:square` to get the value 3. Clojure does not provide any additional protection against making this mistake.